# Same log file in multiple projects using serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a Logger.cs class:

```
public Logger(string logtype=null)
        {
            _logtype = logtype;
            LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Warning;
            if (File.Exists(configPath))
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(configPath);
                string val = xdoc.Descendants("logEnabled").First().Value;
                // if(clientConfig.LogEnabled == true)
                if (val == "true")
                {
                    level = LogEventLevel.Debug;

                }
                else if (val == "false")
                {
                    level = LogEventLevel.Warning;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                level = LogEventLevel.Warning;
            }
           _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                         .WriteTo.File(_filepath, level)
                         .CreateLogger();

        }
```

this logger class is used in multiple projects in a solution. Like shown below:

```
    Class A {
     Logger _logger = new Logger("A");
    }

Class A1 {
     Logger _logger = new Logger("A");
    }

Class B {
     Logger _logger = new Logger("B");
    }

Class B1 {
     Logger _logger = new Logger("A");
    }
```

With my above code. Now i can see only the first logging is written to the log file. Class A and Class A1 are using the same log file "A", when my program executes i can see only Class A logging is present in the log but not class A1 logging messages.
Same for Class B and Class B1, only class B messages are visible.

How can i use the same log file across multiple project in a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to enable multi-process shared log files, set `shared` to `true`

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.File(_filepath, level, shared: true)
                .CreateLogger();
```

For more check [Shared log files](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#shared-log-files)

Comment: How can this property set via appsetting.json?

Comment: @user1066231 Try `"WriteTo": [{ "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "log.txt", "shared": "true" } }]`